# How to use wait_for in discord.py rewrite

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have been making a discord bot and tried making commands that use reactions. I have seen that using wait_for is the best way of achieving exacly that. If anyone could provide some examples for:

• Using reactions to give roles

• Using reactions to create a channel

• Using reactions to edit a message

If you could break down the code line by line so i could learn it instead if just copy pasting, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: The [docs has an example](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for). If you don't understand a line ask that specifically. If you don't know how to give a role, create a channel or edit a message ask that specifically. The docs also explain that. Rather than asking to be fed the information (while it is out there) it is better to ask what exactly you don't understand.

Comment: I dont understand how to use wait_for with reactions. I already know how to create a channel give a role etc.

Comment: The link provides an example for reactions `reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)`

Comment: How would i do the check?

Comment: The link I provided has an example on how to do the check.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has an great explanation but can be difficult to understand at first,
usually reaction roles is done like this (if we leave databases out for now):

```py
reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction')

if str(reaction.emoji) == '':
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='thumbsup')
    await user.add_roles(role)

elif str(reaction.emoji) == '':
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='thumbsdown')
    await user.add_roles(role)
```

but this code can be optimized like this, it also simulates a database:

```py
reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction')
roles = {'': 'thumbsup', '': 'thumbsdown'}

role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=roles[str(reaction.emoji)])
await user.add_roles(role)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i generally use as it implements checks

```
message = ctx.send("message")
reactions = [...]
def check(r:discord.reaction, u:discord.user):
    checker = message.id == reaction.message.id
    checker = checker and u == message.author
    checker = checker and r in reactions
    return checker

while true:
    reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for("reaction_add",check=check)
    if reaction == reactions[0]:
        ctx.send("reaction one")
    elif reaction == reactions[1]:
        ctx.send("reaction two")
    elif reaction == reactions[2]:
        break
```

If you want you can also have a list of users that can react and in the check check if the user is in users
in discord you can do member == user